# jQuery not working with other files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, head

I'm just starting to learn about jQuery and I believe I have run into a road block. Essentially what I have is a  that represents a clickable area with an  inside. So I'm trying to use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#side_menu_icon').click(function(){
    $('#side_menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
```

Where `#side_menu_icon` is the clickable area and `#side_menu` is just a placeholder  with width,height, and color temporarily. By default I've set this `<div>` to display:none; because the example I was looking at did the same thing, assuming the jQuery function would set it to visible. When I click the area nothing happens, I've tried attaching the `#side_menu_icon` to both the `<img>` and the `<div>`. I think there might be something I don't understand about the  and how documents inherit the code from one another so I'll include that as well:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <title>Test Blog Site</title>
</head>
```

main.js is the file that calls the jQuery functions above.

Thanks for your time, I hope this is enough information for a solution.

EDIT:
Cut down version of HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="top_bar">
        <h1 style="padding-left:1em;">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="side_menu_icon">
        <img src="images/side-menu-closed-15px.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="side_menu">
    </div>
    <div id="post_holder">
        <img style="margin-bottom:-5px" src="images/post-collection-top-transparent.gif" />
        <div id="post_collection">
            <!-- stuff -->
        </div>
        <img src="images/post-collection-bottom-transparent.gif" />
    </div>

</body>
```

Relavent sections being

```
        <div id="side_menu_icon">
        <img src="images/side-menu-closed-15px.gif" />
    </div>
```

and

```
        <div id="side_menu">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: "Courier New";
background-image: url("../images/background-1728x1080.jpg");
background-size:100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
margin: 0;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
outline-offset:0px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,div,p{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.post{
width:90%;
padding-left: 5%;
}

#top_bar{
width: 100%;
z-index:99;
position: fixed;
font-size:15px;
background-image: url("../images/item-background.jpg");
background-size:6%;
color: white;
}

#side_menu_icon{
border: 4px solid #6e3b10;
margin-top: 50px;
position:fixed;
right:0;
background-image: url("../images/item-background.jpg");
}

#post_holder{
z-index:98;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
position:relative;
}

#post_collection{
background-image: url("../images/post-background.gif");
background-size: 100%;
max-width: 900px;
text-align:left;
margin: auto;
}

#side_menu{
height:500px;
    width:100px;
background-color:yellow;
display:none;
}
```

Relevant parts being #side_menu and #side_menu_icon I guess.

Comment: if the `#side_menu_icon` is being loaded dynamically, `$('#side_menu_icon').click(function(){` would have to be replaced with `$(document).on('click', '#side_menu_icon', function(){` Apart from that, I do not see an issue.

Comment: @Ian -- My mistake, read the numbers wrong and thought it was a terribly out-dated version, deleting previous, ignore.

Comment: @tymeJV Haha I see. I would hope no one would dare use a version as old as you were thinking. I couldn't imagine using anything older than like 1.7.2, let alone the newest

Comment: @Ian Sometimes you never know, all it takes is one bad teacher / intro tutorial unfortunately :\

Comment: Show us your relevant HTML and CSS so we can see the whole picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added the requested changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question, some of the CSS was disrupting jQuery's ability to work properly. I will just have to find some way around that.